# Android Recyclerview add item and notifyiteminserted causes blink recycled view before draw the correct

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview as a chat, with some improvements to best performance. For example, when I set the adapter to the recyclerview, I have:

```
listOfMessages.apply {
            adapter = chatMessageAdapter
            val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true)
            linearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
            setHasFixedSize(false)
            layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
            itemAnimator = null
            (listOfMessages.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, listOfMessages.bottom/2)
}
```

And in adapter, I set stableIds, with hash:
`conversationsAdapter?.setHasStableIds(true)` And when return itemId: `messageList[position].hashCode().toLong()`.

And when I add a new item to that recyclerview, I call:

```
listOfMessages?.post {
    chatMessageAdapter?.let { adapter ->
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(0)
        (listOfMessages.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, listOfMessages.bottom/2)
}
```

The list appears to have a good performance, but there's still one problem that I can't find a solution:
Like Whatsapp or Instagram, when I add a message, the view is drawn too fast that appears that the view was previously drawn and after added to the list. But in my case, when I add a new message to the chat list, the message added blinks with the text of the last item shown (the item that "detached" on the list view), and after that the item corrects itself, but with the cost of that "crazy view blink". How can I achieve the whatsapp or Instagram example, that the view draw correct already when added, not blinking first? I don't know if it's a problem with recycled view or what.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the new view from showing text from the second last view. override `onViewRecycled(VH holder)` and using holder of right type set textView's text to empty.
To prevent the blinking of newly added view you can disable the default item animator using `recyclerView.setDefaultItemAnimator(null).

Comment: I had a similar use case.  I used 'rv.setItemAnimator(null)' so you may want to edit your method as I don't believe there is a "...setDefaultItemAnimator(null)".